# Extracting parts of data from a google spreadsheet to a google document

Tags: google-apps-script

i have a google spreadsheet which has the following 7 columns: 1) room number, 2) waiter 1 name, 3) waiter 2 name, 4) waiter 3 name, 5) waiter 1 experience, 6) waiter 2 experience, 7) waiter 3 experience. i want to create a document or pdf from the spreadsheet with just 3 columns: 1) room number, 2) waiter names, 3) waiter experiences. That is, it should be in such a way that the waiter names and waiter experiences for all the 3 waiters is one below the other for each room. The data is now presented in only 3 columns instead of 7. Any clues how do i write a google apps script for doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you ever played with blocks when you were a kid ?  In this code You should do the same : extract cells data and re-combine it the way you want...

A couple of `for loops` do the job pretty easily, the code below shows one way to do it, it creates a new sheet in the original spreadsheet and a new document with the data shown in a table.

You'll have to add some formatting improvements to make it look nicer but the data is there and that's the main point of your question.

```
function myFunction() {
  var sh = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var ss = sh.getActiveSheet();
  var inputRange = ss.getRange(1,1,ss.getLastRow(),7);
  var data = inputRange.getValues();
  Logger.log(data);
  var newData = [];
  newData.push(['Room Number','Waiter Name','Waiter experience']);
  for(var n=1;n<data.length;++n){
    for(var c=0;c<7;c=c+2){
      var row = [];
      if(c==0){row.push(data[n][0]) ; c++}else{row.push(' ')};
      row.push(data[n][c]);
      row.push(data[n][c+1]);
      newData.push(row);
      Logger.log(row);
    }
  }
  Logger.log(newData);
  sh.insertSheet().getRange(1,1,newData.length,newData[0].length).setValues(newData);
  var doc = DocumentApp.create('New Waiter list').getBody().appendTable(newData);
}
```

---

**EDIT :** here is how to handle formatting of the document table - I just can't make the horizontal alignment work.... *don't know why*.

```
function reformatTable() {
  var sh = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var ss = sh.getSheets()[0];// here I chose to always get the first sheet in the spreadsheet
  var inputRange = ss.getRange(1,1,ss.getLastRow(),7);
  var data = inputRange.getValues();
  var newData = [];
  newData.push(['Room Number','Waiter Name','Waiter experience']);
  for(var n=1;n<data.length;++n){ // skip headers by starting at 1
    for(var c=0;c<7;c=c+2){
      var row = [];
      if(c==0){row.push(data[n][0]) ; c++}else{row.push('')};
      row.push(data[n][c])
      row.push(data[n][c+1]);
      newData.push(row);
    }
  }
  sh.insertSheet().getRange(1,1,newData.length,newData[0].length).setValues(newData);
  var doc = DocumentApp.create('New Waiter list'); // create document
  var table = doc.getBody().appendTable(newData); // create table in a separate process so I can set the style below
  var style = {};
  style[DocumentApp.Attribute.HORIZONTAL_ALIGNMENT] = DocumentApp.HorizontalAlignment.CENTER; // this one has no effect
  style[DocumentApp.Attribute.FONT_FAMILY] = DocumentApp.FontFamily.ARIAL;
  style[DocumentApp.Attribute.FONT_SIZE] = 10;
  style[DocumentApp.Attribute.FOREGROUND_COLOR] = '#0000ff';
  style[DocumentApp.Attribute.BORDER_COLOR] = '#dddddd' ;
  table.setAttributes(style);
}
```